# Filled map by postal codes for Poland shows whole country

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have postal codes for Poland (more than 22000). If put into the filled map in Power Bi – it is showing the whole territory of the country, even though if I put codes’ aggregated territories into the legend.
The communication is as: ”too many values, not showing all data”.
If filters are put to reduce the number of data the system shows as follows:
“more location data is required to create a filled map. To create a filled map, the location data should include Bing Map-supported geographic data, such as country/region, state/province, or postal code.”
I would deeply appreciate for any comments or help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the error message the filled map visual is relying on Bing Maps to provide the "fill". I'm not familiar with the geography of Poland but typical this would be a county, or state, or other geographic unit.  Bing Maps would then provide the polygon that outlines the areas and fill the polygon depending on your chosen data values. Postcodes tend to be either points or very small areas.

22000 postcodes does not sound like a lot for a whole country and it may be that for Poland there are small area polygons-one for each postcode area. However, it's likely that Bing Maps is either not aware of these, or they don't exist, or it's making a best effort to fill the map based on the 22000 data points which is throwing the "too many values..." error. If you can add some higher level hierachical data to your dataset such as the state or county for each postcode then Bing Maps may be able to provide the necessary polygons to the filled map visual to display what you need.  You say you have used codes to aggregate the postcodes into territories.  This should work if Bing Maps can interpret the codes/territories, but it appears it cannot.
I checked this
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poland#Administrative_divisions
and tested Bing Maps by searching for some of the divisions and Bing correctly draws a polygon around the searched division.  You could try these as your hierachy to aggreagate the postcodes.

If your still having isses with the filled map you could take more control over the mapping and use a different visual such as shape map (in preview) or Choropleth Drilldown (available from Marketplace). However, with these you will need to provide the base maps shapefile in topojson format (e.g. the polygons of the territories that you refer to). I don't know how easy these would be to get for Poland, but in my experience these options give better control of the final output but require more initial configuration.

I've assumed that what you want is a filled map (i.e. polygon based).  However, if you're looking at mapping point data - such as the postcodes themselves - then an alternative such as the Map visual or Mapbox  visual (better imho but in preview and not free for heavy usage). Also for these visuals you may need to provide additional spatial data such as latitude and longitude for each postcode.